# Can you arrange column display order using Diagram view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm creating tables in SQL Server > Diagram view, i just find it easier sometimes to do all the relationships, etc.  Anyways, I was having trouble re-arranging the order of the columns while i'm in Diagram view, It thinks i want to make it a relationship/key instead of dragging the column before/after another one. It works fine when in the standard table creation screen (the re-arranging part) but not when i'm in Diagram view, why is that?  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible, can only Cut the row then insert the row and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to do what you would like here. In theory, if it were to allow you to change the order of the columns it would be changing the underlying table which is not possible without dropping the table first.